# How to find active training partners through Endomondo?

Tags: running, skiing

I have used Endomondo now many years for sports such as skiing, running and racewalking. It has my training plan for half-marathon and a lot of results showing progress but I feel very alone in using it. I would like to find some active users of it, competitive athletics and some champions. It would be cool to associate with other professional athletes there or just wannabes. Most of my local professional friends are not using this service while some less-active people are using it. Basically, I don't care where they are -- it would be cool to find athletes with similar progress and results so competition with them even virtually would make some sense.

> **How do you find active training partners through Endomondo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to www.endomondo.com and hit the Friends option. It'll allow you to search for people you may know and also has teams, challenges, and events.

I'm training for Pikes Peak Marathon but cant even get my own family to use it or even friend me :P

Answer (score 0):

Sign up to a local race, run at your rithm, look who run at your rithm and join their clubs. Then you can convince them to use Endomondo and befriend you. Don't let the technology choose your friends :)

A bit more seriously, I used Endomondo barely. In RunGPS you can locate people with ease, but in the years I've been using it I have never contacted or been contacted spontaenously by other people. I don't think it is for the program, but for the runner's culture. Then, I don't think befriending people through software like these is the best approach to finding running mates. So I'd suggest you again to check the local clubs and asking them to let you train with them before joining.